# Cypher: Return path where begin and end may be equal

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a taxonomy as a Neo4j graph. The basic structure is like this:

```
taxonomyName -HAS_ROOT_TERM-> root -IS_BROADER_THAN-> term -IS_BROADER_THAN-> term'-IS_BROADER_THAN-> term'' - ...
```

Now I want for a given term - e.g. term'' - its path from the taxonomy root (or multiple paths; please note that there may be multiple taxonomies with multiple eligible roots, the structure is actually a poly-hierarchy):

```
START n=node:index("id:term''Id")
MATCH p = taxonomy-[:HAS_ROOT_TERM]->r-[:IS_BROADER_THAN*]->n
RETURN TAIL(EXTRACT(n in NODES(p) : n.id))
```

The `TAIL` excludes the first node to that I don't get back the taxonomy node itself. This works fine, except when I directly query for a root term. Then nothing is returned. Of course: I search a path with at least three elements, the taxonomy node, a root node and any descendant of the root. Now I'd need to express that `r` and `n` may be equal. I tried to make the `IS_BROADER_THAN` relationship optional, but then just null is returned because the pattern cannot be found.

So how do I restrict my query to paths including a root term and allowing paths of length one, only containing a root term?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typical "RTFM" case, I'm afraid ;-)

The documentation at http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-match.html#match-zero-length-paths tells us, that

```
... root -[:IS_BROADER_THAN*0..]-> term ...
```

does the trick. Only specifying the asterisk assumes a `1..` range. With `0..`, start and end node may be the same, i.e. the relationship may not have been traversed at all.